# Python Requests 'Permission denied' but works with sudo

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssl, python-requests

I am using Python Requests library to connect to a REST server by using .pem certificates to authenticate who I am to establish a connection so I can start collecting data, parsing it, etc. When I run my program via Eclipse or the terminal, I get this error:

```
[('system library', 'fopen', 'Permission denied'), ('BIO routines', 'FILE_CTRL', 'system lib'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file', 'system lib')]
```

However, if I run as 'sudo' - the requests library works as intended and I am able to retrieve the data. Unfortunately, running as 'sudo' has side effects that where the default Python interpreter is the root interpreter, which is Python2. However, there are a lot of library dependencies that are needed from Anaconda.

For context, here is the function I am using to establish a connection:

```
PEM_FILE = os.path.expanduser("path/to/pem/file.pem")   #Path is to a folder in root level
    def set_up_connection(self):

    #URL's to request a connection with
    rest_auth = 'https://www.restwebsite.com/get/data'

    ip_address = self.get_ip_address()

    body = json.dumps({'userid':'user', 'password':'pass', 'ip_address':ip_address})

    try:
        resp = self.session.post(rest_auth, data=body, cert=PEM_FILE, verify=False)
        values = resp.json()
        token = values['token']

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        token = None

    return token, ip_address
```

TLDR; Using 'python rest_connector.py' renders an error. Running that command as sudo works.

Context for the certificates: The .pem cert permissions is set to 600 (rw-------).

To try and solve my problem running as sudo, I have started a terminal and run 'sudo -Es' which sets the terminal to run as root and uses Anaconda as my default interpreter, BUT I end up with a handshake error:

```
[('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'ssl handshake failure')]
```

If someone can help me solve it this way, it would be a nice temporary fix, but I still need to be able to run this without sudo.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Who owns the .pem file?

Comment: Can you change the owner of the file `~/path/to/pem/file.pem` to the be user who runs the script?

Comment: Root owned the file. I just tried to change the owner to myself using 'sudo chown username file.pem'. Still getting a handshake error.

Comment: try chmod 400 ~/path/to/pem/file.pem

Comment: @DmgCtrl-b.net: do a `cat path/to/pem/file.pem` as the user of the script. If this fails because of missing permissions either the file itself is not readable or any directory above is not executable. This means it might not be enough to make permission or ownership changes only to the file but you must make changes to the directory where the file is in, the directory where this directory is in etc.

Comment: That command runs successfully: "cat: /home/username/../../etc/pki/tls/private/: Is a directory"

Comment: Do I need to change the permissions of my python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to solve this and I'll post what I did in case anyone else stumbles upon this with a similar problem.

Permissions being set to 600 for the certs and pem file, ownership being set to root, and performing the openssl hashing function, the only problem was where the certs were placed in the sub directories.

While I placed the certs into 'etc/pki/tls/certs', they actually belonged in 'etc/ssl/certs'. The same goes for the .pem file except that .pem would be placed in a restricted folder, 'private'. After moving the files to the correct folder. Then I was able to set the verify param for the request to the cert_path and everything worked like I needed it to.

```
resp = self.session.post(rest_auth, data=body, cert=PEM_FILE, verify=cert_path)
```

'etc/pki/tls/certs' is the directory for Fedora distribution of Linux. 'etc/ssl/certs' is the directory for the Ubuntu distribution of Linux.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

The username needs to be able to read the file. You can verify by running `ls path_to_file.pem`.

If you have changed ownership of the file, you might still be missing executable permissions on the directories containing the file.

You can potentially fix that with `chmod -R +x ~/path/to_directory_containing_perm`

Comment: I changed the permissions to the file using that command but, no luck. Still getting a handshake error.

Comment: So, the exception is now different after changing the permissions. Sorry I didn't notice this last night, but it now looks like the exception after I run as 'sudo -Es': 

`[('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca'), ('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'ssl handshake failure')]`